# Log to files in Ada

Tags: ada

Is there any way to **make logs** to text files in Ada? I'm doing a academic work and i need that functionality.

I think that I need some library like `Ada.IO.`

Some help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ada.Text_IO for direct text output to files. There are plenty of examples on the net. It should look like:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is
   F : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Create(File => F,
                      Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Out_File,
                      Name => "out.txt");
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(File => F,
                        Item => "My log message");
   Ada.Text_IO.Close(File => F);
end Test;
```

For more advanced logging capabilities, you can consider using external libraries such as Alog (http://www.codelabs.ch/alog/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

There are several Ada logging frameworks, rather than just going with plain text:

- [Alog](http://www.codelabs.ch/alog/)
- [GNATCOLL.Traces](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/gnat-component-collection/)
- [Log4Ada](http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-main-i386/liblog4ada2-dev_1.2-3_i386.deb.html)
- [AWS.Log](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/aws/) package in AWS
- [IAL.Log](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/) package in YAMI4

Comment: Some updated links: [overview](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-114-logging-with-gnatcoll-traces) and [docs](https://docs.adacore.com/gnatcoll-docs/traces.html) for GNATCOLL.Traces, and a working link for [Log4Ada](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4ada/). Another good alternative for a log4j-inspired logger is contained in [Utilada](https://alire.ada.dev/crates/utilada).